# How to style NavigationRailDestination?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, menu, flutter-layout

I have a `List` of  `NavigationRailDestination`s which I would like to have a circular white background, among other things. How can I style this Widget? Wrapping it with a Container doesn't work since `NavigationRail`only accepts a list of `NavigationRailDestination`s. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

```
List<NavigationRailDestination> _buildDestinations() {
    return [
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.home_outlined,
        ),
        label: Text('Dashboard'),
      ),
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.person_outline_rounded,
        ),
        label: Text('Profile'),
      ),
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.coffee_outlined,
        ),
        label: Text('Jobs'),
      ),
      const NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.event_note_rounded,
        ),
        label: Text('Events'),
      ),
    ];
  }
```

[image: UI Design]

Comment: can you include your ui design too?

Comment: the image you added doesn't contain those style you want! I want to know what kind of style you are talking about.

Comment: For example, I'd like the icons to have a circular white background. @eamirho3ein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting background for icon you can do this:

```
NavigationRailDestination(
    icon: Container(
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Icon(
        Icons.home_outlined,
      ),
    ),
    label: Text('Dashboard'),
  ),
```

[image]